# Does it make sense to use RequireJS to just load scripts in the index page of an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have an Angular app where I am loading my dependent libraries directly via multiple script tags (i.e. angular.min.js, angular-route.min.js, etc.). Does it make sense to use requirejs in this instance to load them instead of having them in the bottom of the index page. Angular has dependency injection, so I unlike a backbone app, I am not seeing the large advantage:

```
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

It seems like a lot of overhead to create a main.js such as:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: "/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min",
    bootstrap: "/libs/bootstrap.min",
    angular: "/libs/angular.min.js",
    angularrouter: "/libs/angular-route.min.js",
    angularresource: "/libs/angular-resource.min.js",
    services: "services/services.js",
    controllers: "/controllers/controllers.js",
    app: "app.js"
},
shim: {
    bootstrap: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'Bootstrap'
    },
    angularrouter: {
        deps: ['angular'],
        exports: 'AngularRouter'
    },
    angularresource: {
        deps: ['angular'],
        exports: 'AngularResource'
    },
}
});

require(['jquery', 'boostrap', 'angular', 'angularrouter', 'angularresource', 'services', 'controllers', 'app'], 

function ($, Bootstrap, angular, AngularRouter, AngularResource, services, controllers, app) {
angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
});
```

And then try to perform some sort of reference in the app.js:

define(['jquery', 'boostrap', 'angular', 'angularrouter', 'angularresource', 'services', 'controllers', 'app'], function ($, Bootstrap, angular, AngularRouter, AngularResource, services, controllers) {

Comment: We are using this approach for our production system. We also use RequireJS to create a single js file in build process, which can save some HTTP requests.

Comment: For small projects, I just bundle the scripts or include them automatically using the build system (Grunt without RequireJS). For larger projects I want to be able to split my code into lazy loadable bundles and I am making [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Comment: Is there a good example of straight requires + angular given my needs as well?

Comment: Here is an example angular-requirejs seed project, which you might find helpful: https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed